Why is Linux not sending ICMP6 problem parameter message
I'm performing testing for USGv6 certification against a Linux build made using Yocto (Poky distribution version 5.0 - Scarthgap, Kernel 6.6). All required tests are passing except one: an echo request is sent to the test system with the next header value set to 252 (unknown). The test system is expected to NOT send an echo reply (it doesn't) but instead send a ICMP6 parameter problem message (type ICMPV6_PARAMPROB with the code ICMPV6_UNK_NEXTHDR) -- it isn't sending the ICMP6 message. This fails to comply with the requirements in RFC 8883 section 2.2. Is there something that must be configured in order to have the required ICMP6 error message sent?
I've cleared the ip6tables of all rules, so that shouldn't be the issue. I've also looked into the various sysctl properties that can be set, but none would seem to block an ICMP6 message from being sent. This is a single test, so we are nowhere near any maximum limits for messages. Tcpdump shows the echo request is being received by the system under test. Is there any other place I should check?
